# MySql Connection String localhost

Tags: mysql, connection-string

I need to compose the connection string for my WebApiCore application now running on Linux.

I tried something like this:

`server=localhost;uid=User;pwd=Password;database=Database;`

but I always get this error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or
>   instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to
>   SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify
>   that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to
>   allow remote connections

What am I doing wrong or what am I missing?

I think the problem lays in `localhost` keyword, but I can't figure out what to use

Thanks for the help

Comment: you might need to specify the port? `port=3306`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your question is in regards to MySQL, but the client is attempting to connect to a SQL Server database.